# How to use categorical vectors in ape (r) for phylogenetic independent contrasts

Tags: r, correlation, phylogeny

I have been performing phylogenetically independent contrasts of several ecological variables for the cat phylogeny, using the `ape` package in R, and I was wondering how this can be done using categorical values.

Here is how it works using numeric values:

```
# Load ape
library(ape)

# Simulate data
set.seed(23)
phy <- rcoal(10)
x <- runif(10, 0, 10)
y <- x + rnorm(10)

# Compute correlation of independent contrasts
cor.test(pic(y, phy), pic(x, phy))
```

How can I do independent contrasts with discrete data?

Comment: if you don't get a good answer here you might try the `r-sig-phylo@r-project.org` mailing list

Comment: Thank you for the advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Independent contrasts are only for continuous data. To test for correlations between discrete variables while accounting for phylogenetic non-independence, there are two potential avenues.

1. You can use [phylogenetic logistic regression](http://sysbio.oxfordjournals.org/content/59/1/9.short), as implemented the [`phyloglm`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/phylolm/docs/phyloglm) package.
2. You can use [continuous time Markov models](http://www.jstor.org/stable/49836?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) to test for correlated evolution between a pair of discrete traits. These models are implemented in the standalone software [BayesTraits](http://www.evolution.rdg.ac.uk/BayesTraits.html), or you can follow this excellent [blog post](http://blog.phytools.org/2014/12/r-function-for-pagels-1994-correlation.html) that demonstrates how to implement the test using the `phytools` package.

I should mention that concerns have been raised surrounding the ability of these Markov models to deal with phylogenetic pseudoreplication (see [this paper](http://sysbio.oxfordjournals.org/content/64/1/127.full)), causing me to lean toward the GLM framework.